# How to programmatically remove / uninstall an Eclipse feature and its plugins

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

How can I programmatically uninstall an Eclipse feature together with all its plugins? By uninstall I mean remove all its files so it is not loaded again.

I am working on some plugins that need to be automatically, without any GUI intervention from the user, uninstalled after a period of time has passed.
I tried calling the Bundle.uninstall() methods on the plugins but that just uninstalls them from runtime, it is not a complete removal.

Thanks

*Later edit:
I have since found another post with this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927400/how-do-i-easily-query-a-running-eclipse-for-its-installed-features?rq=1).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Eclipse `p2` provisioning system to uninstall a plugin. It looks like `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.UninstallOperation` is what needs to be run.

I am not familiar with running this, there is some information about using p2 here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseP2Update/article.html

You can also use the `p2 director` to do an uninstall - see http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_director.html